# How to update one field of a Meteor user profile without losing the others?

Tags: meteor

I have set several fields in my user profile. But I want to update one at a time. I do it like this :

```
Meteor.users.update(loggingInUserId, {
  $set: {
    profile: {
      firstName
    }
  }
});
```

When I run this, the new value get updated but all the other fields are removed. Any idea how to do this right?

Example of a user :

```
{
   _id: '11111',
   profile: {
     firstName: 'One',
     lastName: 'Two',
     contact: '34353'
   }
}
```

Now when I run the above command, it will remove the `lastName` and the `contact` fields.

Comment: Are you sure that this is the code that is removing the other fields?

Comment: @ExplosionPills Yes. I just added a sample user collection to clarify the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```js
Meteor.users.update(loggingInUserId, {
  $set: {
    "profile.firstName": newValue
  }
});
```

Comment: Yep. That works like a charm! @Michel's answer explains the issue. Your solution worked.